A differential of a flow and the Jacobian of a vector field on a sphere
I have a vector field on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ of the form $V_x = P_x(f(x))$ where $P_x(y) = y-\langle x,y\rangle x$ is the projection of $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ onto $T_x\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
I am considering a flow on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ defined by this vector field, and my goal is to calculate the differential of a flow map $\phi_t:\mathbb{S}^{d-1}\to \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ locally (i.e., calculate the Jacobi matrix).
By the so-called first variation formula stated here,  we need to estimate the differential (or the Jacobi matrix) of the vector field $V$.
By taking coordinates I can identify $T_x \mathbb{S}^{d-1} \cong \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ and $V$ can be seen as a mapping from $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$. Thus, we can define a gradient of each component $V^i: \mathbb{S}^{d-1}\to \mathbb{R}$.
According to this post, for a submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, the gradient of the restriction $f|_M$ can be calculated by $\nabla (f|_M) = (\nabla f)^{\top}$ where $\top$ is the projection to $TM$.
I want to use this fact to calculate $\nabla V^i$, but I am not sure what $V^i$ would look like in the first place.
So my question is: Am I heading in the right direction? If not, how do we estimate the differential using the usual derivatives of $f$ or a method similar to the formula $\nabla (f|_M) = (\nabla f)^{\top}$?
